# row_number() with an unspecified window `row_number() OVER ()`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm building a paginated scoreboard using postgres 9.1.

There are several criteria that users can sort the scoreboard by, and they can sort by ascending or descending. There is a feature to let users find "their row" across the multiple pages in the scoreboard, and it must reflect the users selected sorting criteria.

I am using postgres's row_number function to find their offset into the result set to return the page where the user can find their row.

Everything I'm reading about row_number seems to imply that **bad things** happen to people who don't specify an ordering within the row_number window. E.g. `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score_1)` is OK, `row_number() OVER ()` is **bad**.

My case is different from the examples I've read about in that I *am* explicitly ordering my query, I realize the DB engine may not return the results in any particular order if I don't.

But I'd like to just specify ordering at the level of the entire query and get the row_number of the results, without having to duplicate my ordering specification with the row_number's window.

So this is what I'd like to do, and it "seems to work".

```
SELECT
  id, 
  row_number() OVER () AS player_position,
  score_1,
  score_2,
  score_3,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY (score_1 ASC | score_1 DESC | score_2 ASC | score_2 DESC | score_3 ASC | score_3 DESC)
```

Where `player_position` reflects the players rank in whatever criteria I'm ordering by.

But the documentation I've read tells me I should do it like this:

```
SELECT
  id, 
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score_1 ASC) AS player_position,
  score_1,
  score_2,
  score_3,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY score_1 ASC
```

or

```
SELECT
  id, 
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score_2 DESC) AS player_position,
  score_1,
  score_2,
  score_3,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY score_2 DESC
```

The real reason that I'd like to avoid redundantly specifying the ordering for the row_number window is to keep my query amenable with the ActiveRecord ORM. I want to have my base scoreboard query, and chain on the ordering.

e.g. Ultimately, I want to be able to do this:

```
Players.scoreboard.order('score_1 ASC')
Players.scoreboard.order('score_2 DESC')
etc...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your main query into a subquery with an ORDER BY and apply the ROW_NUMBER() to the outermost query.

```
SELECT  y.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as player_position
FROM
    (SELECT
        id, 
        score_1,
        score_2,
        score_3,
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY <whatever>) as y
```

Comment: it could work, but I think there's still no guarantee that row_number() without order by will work as expected

Comment: I can't tell how this is different from what I said I'm currently doing (my first code block). What am I missing?

Comment: OK, looking further, I see what you're doing. But my question still stands - Do you have any reason to believe that this would be better than what I'm currently doing? My current solution seems to work, but I'm afraid that it's only coincidence. Is there something about selecting from a subquery that would make it deterministic or more in line with some specification?

Comment: I'm only going from experience when I posted my answer. I don't trust inherent ordering that way, but I don't think I've ever had a subquery reorder the results being passed to the outer query. As far as I know, there is no way to *guarantee* that order, although I suppose you could rewrite this query as a function and just call that -- your ORM would just treat it as a regular SELECT statement, and you would pass in your sort criteria etc to the function.

Comment: Let me try reword the question in my previous comment: Why is it better to select from a subquery than just `SELECT my_table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS player_position FROM my_table ORDER BY <whatever>`

Comment: Maybe someone else with a better knowledge of the Postgresql core code will step forward with a more definitive answer. I don't have much else of substance to add.